# Override default message when @ResponseBody is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to override this behaviour from this Spring class:

```
public class RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor extends AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor {
    ...
    @Override
    protected <T> Object readWithMessageConverters(NativeWebRequest webRequest, MethodParameter parameter,
            Type paramType) throws IOException, HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
            ...
            if (arg == null && checkRequired(parameter)) {
                throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Required request body is missing: " +
                    parameter.getExecutable().toGenericString(), inputMessage);
            }
    ...
}
```

This method handles the error when @ReponseBody is null from a @Controller. I tried to make my own **CustomBodyMethodProcessor** extending from **RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor** like this:

```
public class CustomBodyMethodProcessor extends RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor {

    public CustomBodyMethodProcessor(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        super(converters);
    }

    @Override
    protected <T> Object readWithMessageConverters(NativeWebRequest webRequest, MethodParameter parameter,
                                                   Type paramType) throws IOException, HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {

        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = webRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
        Assert.state(servletRequest != null, "No HttpServletRequest");
        ServletServerHttpRequest inputMessage = new ServletServerHttpRequest(servletRequest);

        Object arg = readWithMessageConverters(inputMessage, parameter, paramType);
        if (arg == null && checkRequired(parameter)) {
            //I want to change this....
            throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Required request body is missing: " +
                    parameter.getExecutable().toGenericString(), inputMessage);
        }
        return arg;
    }

}
```

So, to add the new **CustomBodyMethodProcessor** I did :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements  WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters;


    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.addArgumentResolvers(resolvers);
        resolvers.add(new CustomBodyMethodProcessor(converters));

    }

}
```

But this not works. When I debug, always stops in **readWithMessageConverters** method from **RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor** and not in my overrided method from **CustomBodyMethodProcessor**

I appreciate any help you can provide me !!

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you add yours’ earlier in the list (`resolvers.add(new …, 0);`)? Or remove the other one (`resolvers.removeIf(i -> i instanceof RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor);`) before adding yours’?

Comment: Hi! `resolvers` is empty, no instances of `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` inside. Add mine with index 0 and no results... Thanks!

Comment: Your answer @BeUndead takes me to the right path... https://stackoverflow.com/a/19847526/4267653

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void prioritizeCustomArgumentMethodHandlers () {
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers = new ArrayList<>(adapter.getArgumentResolvers ());
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> customResolvers = adapter.getCustomArgumentResolvers();
        argumentResolvers.removeAll(customResolvers);
        argumentResolvers.addAll (0, customResolvers);
        adapter.setArgumentResolvers (argumentResolvers);
    }
```

My **CustomBodyMethodProcessor** was added to the list of resolvers but original **RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor** has precedence so **CustomBodyMethodProcessor** is never invoked.

The solution was to delete from resolvers my CustomBodyMethodProcessor, give precedence and add it again to the list!

Thanks to this asnwer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19847526/4267653 and to [@BeUndead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2478398/beundead) for the clue !

Comment: No idea if it works in this case, but most spring collections support `implements Ordered`, or `@Order` on the class.  So you could try `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` on your custom class and it may work without this step.  Glad you got it working though.